# PHP Class Property not passing into method

Tags: php, html, class, oop, properties

To start off, I am extremely new to PHP and am trying to understand how to work with an object class.

For several days now I've had a challenge that I haven't been able to solve.  The problem is that a property of a class isn't being called/utilized inside a method of the class.  I know the property isn't empty because I threw in a test method to confirm it.

There must be something I'm missing, and I hope it isn't painfully obvious, as I've spent several days trying different solutions to no avail.

Below is my code with comments:

```
<?php
/*************   global  variables  ******************************/
$company_name = "Stay Cool HVAC";
$street = '12345 Rockwell Canyon Rd.'; 
$company_citystatezip = "Hometown, CA 91777";
$company_address = "<center>$company_name <br/> ". "<center>$street <br />". "<center>$company_citystatezip";

/*************   end global  variables  **************************/

echo '<H1 align="center">PHP Class Example</H1>';

class Company {
//// insert object variables (properties)
var $address;

//// insert methods below here

//// Test to see that address property is set to $company_address variable  
function __get($address){
    return $this->address;  
    }

function getHeader($company_name, $color) {
    $topheader = "<TABLE align='center'; style='background-color:$color;width:50%'><TR><TD>";
    $topheader .= "<H1 style='text-align:center'>$company_name</H1>";
    $topheader .= "</TD></TR></TABLE>";
    return $topheader;                                      
    }

////    The address property isn't passing to output in method
function getFooter($color) {
    $this->address;
    $bottomfooter = "<TABLE align='center'; style='background-color:$color;width:50%'><TR><TD>";
    $bottomfooter .= "<center><b><u>$address</center></b></u>";
    $bottomfooter .= "</TD></TR></TABLE>";
    return $bottomfooter;
    }
}

$companybanner = new Company();
echo $companybanner->getHeader($company_name, gold);
echo "<br/>";
$companybanner->address = "$company_address";
echo $companybanner->getFooter(blue);

// Test to confirm that "address" property is set - working 
echo "<br />";
echo $companybanner->getaddress;
?>
```

Hopefully you can see that the "address" property is suppose to be outputted inside a blue colored table from the "getFooter" method.  Instead, my result is a blue line with no text.  Also, the "address" property isn't null as I did include a test with the "__get($address)" method.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: change `"<center><b><u>$address</center></b></u>";` to `"<center><b><u>$this->address</center></b></u>";` and it will work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should replace

```
function getFooter($color) {
    $this->address;
```

With

```
function getFooter($color) {
    $address = $this->address;
```

?

The way I understaind behavior of php, this line

```
$bottomfooter .= "<center><b><u>$address</center></b></u>";
```

would try to use local variable (local to the function) $address but $address is not defined. As I understand how php works - this line

```
$this->address;
```

would be interpreted in this manner: if address = "abc" is the same as telling interpreter to do

```
"abc";
```

No operations specified.

But I suppose **$address = $this->address;** is not the only way to solve your problem. I think you could use this just fine:

```
$bottomfooter .= "<center><b><u>{$this->address}</center></b></u>";
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: As the different people have pointed out, the solution is to replace "$address" with "$this->address" inside the "getFooter" method. I thank everybody who gave a quick answer, as I am a noob and their knowledge is greatly appreciated.

Thank you again.